# How to show an image inside shapes like back of an phone case(with transparent hole for camera) in the webpage?

Tags: css, xml, html, canvas, svg

I am working on a project in which I am developing a web application where artist can upload there artwork which will be printed on various smartphone phone cases(A small version of websites like RedBubble.com or Society6.com).

So as one of its module, what I want to achieve is:

1. Admin can upload the phone case shapes(just the back of the case
   with transparent camera hole) from admin panel.
2. Artist can upload the artwork and which will be displayed on all
   available phone cases as final product to the customer.

I have searched a lot about this and came out with the following idea but now I am totally lost:

1. Admin can create shapes using software like InkScape which will give them SVG files and its code.
2. These files can be stored in the database(content of the file or the file name, I was unable to figure out).
3. Artist will upload his/her artwork and will be stored in the database as jpg file.

So now, I have both, the shape(SVG) and the artwork(JPG) stored in the database.

I just cannot figure out how to display the final product which will be the selected artwork on the selected phone case shaped SVG. Or am I going totally wrong?

This is what I what to achieve:

http://postimg.org/image/vp267jvp5/

But as you can see that I totally messed it up. Here is the code for the file. SVG was generated from InkScape. I used `pattern` tags to fit in the image.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html>
<body>


<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="212"
   height="360"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.5 r10040"
   sodipodi:docname="shit.svg">
  
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1"
     inkscape:cx="76"
     inkscape:cy="265.01282"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="691"
     inkscape:window-x="-9"
     inkscape:window-y="-9"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     style="display:inline"
     transform="translate(-299,-397.375)">
    <path
  d="m 343,397.375 c -24.376,0 -44,19.624 -44,44 l 0,272 c 0,24.376 19.624,44 44,44 l 124,0 c 24.376,0 44,-19.624 44,-44 l 0,-272 c 0,-24.376 -19.624,-44 -44,-44 l -124,0 z m 18.5,34 c 12.42641,0 22.5,6.71573 22.5,15 0,8.28427 -10.07359,15 -22.5,15 -12.42641,0 -22.5,-6.71573 -22.5,-15 0,-8.28427 10.07359,-15 22.5,-15 z"
  fill="url(#img1)"
  id="rect2985"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
<defs>
 <filter id="blur">
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0"/>
</filter>
    <pattern id="img1" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="212" height="360" >
        <image xlink:href="uploads/artwork.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="212" height="360"  />
    </pattern>
</defs> 
</svg>
<img src="uploads/artwork.jpg" >
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate if you can provide me some steps or examples or tutorial links or should I use some library because I searched and the above is all I got. I am using php and mysql database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by manipulating the SVG by:

1. Turn the cover shape into a clip path
2. dynamically load the user's image into the SVG and apply the clip path to it

[I've made a demo fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/w46gtdsp/)

Here's the code:

```
initCover("svg2", "layer1");
replaceCover("svg2", "layer1", "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/");


function  initCover(svgId, coverId)
{
    // Turn cover into a clipping path
    var svg = document.getElementById(svgId);
    var cover = svg.getElementById(coverId);
    var clipPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "clipPath");
    clipPath.setAttribute("id", "cover-clip");
    if (cover.getAttribute("transform"))
        clipPath.setAttribute("transform", cover.getAttribute("transform"));
    // Copy shape from cover to clipPath (assumes cover has only one child element
    clipPath.appendChild(cover.firstElementChild.cloneNode());
    svg.appendChild(clipPath);
    // Optionally hide the original cover shape
    cover.style.visibility = "hidden";
}


function  replaceCover(svgId, coverId, imageURL)
{
    var svg = document.getElementById(svgId);
    var cover = svg.getElementById(coverId);
    // Get the cover width and height
    var  coverBox = cover.getBBox();
    // Add a new image element for the image
    var  image = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
    image.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", imageURL);
    // Set image size so that the image fills the cover and is centred
    image.setAttribute("width", coverBox.width);
    image.setAttribute("height", coverBox.height);
    image.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid slice");
    image.setAttribute("clip-path", "url(#cover-clip)");
    svg.appendChild(image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use html5 canvas's compositing ability to draw only into your phone-case**

In particular, `context.globalCompositeOperation='source-in'` will display your artwork only in the non-transparent pixels of your phone case.

Start with this image of your phone case where everything is transparent except the phone case:

Then you can use compositing to draw your artwork only over the black case pixels like this:

[image][image]

```
// draw the phone case on the canvas
context.drawImage(phonecase,0,0);

// set compositing to source-in
// future drawings will only be visible where existing pixels are opaque
context.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';

// draw the artwork over the phonecase
// compositing will display the artwork only inside the opaque phonecase pixels
context.drawImage(artCanvas,offsetX,offsetY);

// always clean up! Return compositing to its default mode
context.globalCompositeOperation='source-out';
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

This example adds the ability to resize the artwork and reposition it horizontally and vertically.

Good luck with your project!

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var artCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var artCtx=artCanvas.getContext("2d");

var cw,ch,phone,art;

$scaleslider=$('#scaleslider');
$scaleslider.change(function(){ resetScale(); draw(); })
//
$hslider=$('#hslider');
$hslider.change(function(){ draw(); })
//
$vslider=$('#vslider');
$vslider.change(function(){ draw(); });


// image preloader
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/case.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/art.png");
// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
  for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    imgs.push(img);
    img.onload = function(){ 
      imagesOK++; 
      if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}
//
function start(){
  // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images

  // user friendly names for images
  phone=imgs[0];
  art=imgs[1];

  // size the on-screen canvas to phone size
  cw=canvas.width=phone.width;
  ch=canvas.height=phone.height;

  // resetScale
  resetScale();
  // draw the initial rendering
  draw();
}

function resetScale(){
  var scale=$scaleslider.val()/100;

  // calc the scaled size of the artwork
  var artW=art.width*scale;
  var artH=art.height*scale;
  // size the off-screen canvas to allow 2x2 of art images   
  artCanvas.width=artW*2;
  artCanvas.height=artH*2;
  // draw a grid of 2x2 art images to allow horizontal
  // and vertical repositioning
  artCtx.drawImage(art,0,0,artW,artH);
  artCtx.drawImage(art,artW,0,artW,artH);
  artCtx.drawImage(art,artW,artH,artW,artH);
  artCtx.drawImage(art,0,artH,artW,artH);
  // set offsets used in horiz & vert repositioning
  $hslider.attr('max',artW);
  $hslider.val(0);
  $vslider.attr('max',artH);
  $vslider.val(0);    
}

// draw the artwork inside the phone case
// Use the slider values to reposition the artwork
function draw(){
  var offsetX=-$hslider.val();
  var offsetY=-$vslider.val();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.drawImage(phone,0,0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
  ctx.drawImage(artCanvas,offsetX,offsetY);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Scale Artwork<input id=scaleslider type=range min=25 max=150 value=100><br>
Move Horizontally:<input id=hslider type=range min=0 max=200 value=100><br>
Move Vertically:<input id=vslider type=range min=0 max=200 value=100><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```